# unable to pass variable in soundex() postgres using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I want to use Postgres soundex() for my query but I am unable to pass variable inside the soundex()

I have tried below syntaxes but none of them have worked so any help will be appreciated

location.rb

```
# function used in the query and this runs perfectly with static search query
def self.execute_sql(*sql_array)     
   connection.execute(send(:sanitize_sql_array, sql_array))
end

dog = "dog"

Location.execute_sql("SELECT * FROM locations WHERE soundex(name_int) = soundex("+dog+")")

Location.execute_sql('SELECT * FROM locations WHERE soundex(name_int) = soundex("#{dog}")')

Location.execute_sql("SELECT * FROM locations WHERE soundex(name_int) = soundex(#{dog})")
```

Answer (score 2):

Whoever wrote your `execute_sql` method intended it to be used like this, to prevent SQL injection attacks:

```
Location.execute_sql("SELECT * FROM locations WHERE soundex(name_int) = soundex(?)", dog)
```